# Two macros on one button in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which resets the formatting of a particular worksheet and VBA code which searches for data. I want the button which currently executes the search to firstly remove all of the pre-existing formatting.

The worksheet is called List, the macro for reset is called Reset1.

Can someone please tell me how I would go about making this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if I understand it right, you want your button click to first alter the formatting and then to do the data search? If that is the case, the simplest answer is to not modify your button or your formatting code, but instead add this single line into the search code right at the top:

`Call FormattingMacro`

That will cause your macro code to jump to your formatting macro, run, then return to the search macro at the next line. Does that help?

Comment: Hello SandPiper, thank you for your reply. Using 'Call Reset1' at the beginning of the VBA script works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your button has a Caption. Let that caption be "Search" when you load the form. Let the procedure which executes the search also change the button's caption to, say, "Reformat". Now, when the button is clicked it calls the Button_Click procedure which checks the caption and determines which procedure to call depending upon the current caption.